# delegate() in PrototypeJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, delegation

I am used to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), which has a [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) method. So let's say I have HTML like this:

```
<div id="covers">
   <a href="#"><img ... /></a>
   <a href="#"><img ... /></a>
   <a href="#"><img ... /></a>
   <a href="#"><img ... /></a>
   <a href="#"><img ... /></a>
   <a href="#"><img ... /></a>
   ...lots anchors here...
</div>
```

In jQuery, I can bind events to the parent div and not attach individual handlers to new, dynamically added anchors using `delegate()` like so:

```
$('#covers').delegate('a', 'click', function(){
   /// stuff I want to do
   var clickedAnchor = $(this);
});
```

What would the equivalent code be in [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prototype's philosophy is that you do it more like in pure javaScript only with added cross-browser abstractions (plus releasing once a year, plus polluting native prototypes).

<strike>So there's no `delegate` in Prototype.</strike> You can use [Event#findElement](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/prototype/findElement/) though.

```
$('covers').observe('click', function (event) {
  var link = event.findElement('a');

  if (link) {
      // ...
  }
});
```

---

**Edit:** There *is* `delegate` in Prototype: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/on/!

```
$('covers').on('click', 'a', function (event, element) {
   // ...
});
```

Comment: So, looks like it would be: `$('#covers').observe('click', function(evt){
 var clickedAnchor = event.findElement('a');
 if (clickedAnchor) {
       /// stuff I want to do
 }
});`

Comment: Ah, right, forgot I wasn't using `$$`. The `on` handler looks like it does it.

Comment: works for mouseover also (not hover! it's mouseover as vanilla ofc) :)